# AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: jpa

I have one  exception, which yold what I have no mapping on table. But I have this
Exeption is : \
AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: Relative.people in Person.relations

Relative entity is here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "relation")
public class Relative extends AbstractModel<UUID> implements Model<UUID> {

    private UUID id;
    private Person person;
    private RelationTypeEnum relation;

    public Relative() {
    }

    @Override
    public void assignId() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @Override
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id", nullable=false)
    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    @Column(name = "relation")
    public RelationTypeEnum getRelation() {
        return relation;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public void setRelation(RelationTypeEnum relation) {
        this.relation = relation;
    }
}
```

And Person entity is here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person extends AbstractModel<UUID> implements Model<UUID> {

    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private List<Relative> relations;

    @Override
    public void assignId() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @Override
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Relative.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy="people")
    public List<Relative> getRelations() {
        return relations;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String username) {
        this.name = username;
    }

    public void setRelations(List<Relative> relations) {
        this.relations = relations;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? `people` should be a property of the entity `Relative`. Use `person` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Just changed

```
@Table(name = "people")
```

to

```
@Table(name = "person")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a project which included a copy of the jar causing this issue. It was a web project which is including the jar inside its lib i.e. 2 copies of the same jar one with a different class version. Only discovered this when I physically opened the main ear and found the 2nd jar inside a web project.